# Auto update sum of rows & columns in a table

Tags: javascript, html

This issue has been dealt with earlier by @enhzflep and @Rob Schmuecker: Thanks for all the effort.
I am able to get the sum of each row. But I cannot get the sum of each column (at the footer). For now I want to avoid using event listener. What am I doing wrong?
Note that I am a beginner & my knowledge is limited to HTML, CSS, javascript for now. I am progressing gradually.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chem help</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif; padding: 1px;}
th {font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; 
border-style: solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
td {font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; 
border-style: solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
#sn {text-align: right;}
.fin {text-align: right;}
.fin:focus {background-color: rgb(255,255,150);}
.negRed {text-align: right; background-color: rgb(250,200,200);}
.posNorm {text-align: right; background-color: rgb(255,255,255)}
.nofoc {font-weight: bold; text-align: right;}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="pr">
<tbody>
<tr id="thd">
<th>s/n</th>
<th>Ddn1</th>
<th>Ddn2</th>
<th>Ddn3</th>
<th>Ddn4</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="sn" />1</td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="sn" />2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="sn" />3</td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
</tr>

<tfoot id="tft">
<tr>
<td class="nofoc">Total</td>
<td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
function update(element) {
var a = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].value;
var c = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].children[0].value;
var e = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0].value;
var g = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[4].children[0].value;
console.log(a, c, e, g);

<!-- Set all NaN value to 0 -->
if (a === "" || isNaN(a)) {
    a = 0;
}
if (c === "" || isNaN(c)) {
    c = 0;
}
if (e === "" || isNaN(e)) {
    e = 0;
}
if (g === "" || isNaN(g)) {
    g = 0;
}

    var b = parseInt(a);
    var d = parseInt(c);
    var f = parseInt(e);
    var h = parseInt(g);

    <!-- Alert for -ve input, alphabets... cell turns red -->
    if (b < 0) {
    element.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
    } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
    }
    if (d < 0) {
    element.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
    } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
    }
    if (f < 0) {
    element.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
    } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
    }
    if (h < 0) {
    element.parentElement.parentElement.children[4].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
    } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[4].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
    }

    var y = (b + d + f + h);    <!-- Sum deductions -->

    <!-- Alert for NaN value.. cell turns red -->
    if (isNaN(y)) {
        y = 0;
    }

    <!-- Alert for -ve input. Total = 0 & cell turns red -->
    if (b < 0 || d < 0 || f < 0 || h < 0) {
    y = 0;
    element.parentElement.parentElement.children[5].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
    } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[5].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
    }

    element.parentElement.parentElement.children[5].children[0].value = y;

    var table = document.getElementById("pr"); 
    var nuRow = document.getElementById("pr").rows.length;
    var t = nuRow - 1;
    var colSum1, colSum2, colSum3, colSum4, colSum5;
    var v;
    var row;

        for(v = 1; v < t; v++){
            row = table.rows[t];
          colSum1 = colSum1 + b;
          colSum2 = colSum2 + d;
          colSum3 = colSum3 + f;
          colSum4 = colSum4 + h;
          colSum5 = colSum5 + y;

element.row.children[1].children[0].value = colSum1;
element.row.children[2].children[0].value = colSum2;
element.row.children[3].children[0].value = colSum3;
element.row.children[4].children[0].value = colSum4;
element.row.children[5].children[0].value = colSum5;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you describe "this isn't working" more detailed? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Can you share a jsFiddle of your code?

Comment: Btw.: Why do you use html comments inside your script tag? I'd recommend you use Javascript comments  ("//" or "/**/") instead

Comment: `element.parentElement.parentElement.children[5].children[0]` - This is super duper fragile (and all but unmaintainable).

Comment: Why are you closing td like this? `<td />`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot issues in your code.

1. Premature closing of `<td />`!
2. Reusing the same `id`, which is the worst!
3. Putting `<tfoot>` inside `<tbody>`!
4. Finally, most important, your code is not readable at all!

**Non-Working Final HTML**

The below code is not working, but at least free from errors!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chem help</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif; padding: 1px;}
      th {font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; 
        border-style: solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
      td {font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; 
        border-style: solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
      #sn {text-align: right;}
      .fin {text-align: right;}
      .fin:focus {background-color: rgb(255,255,150);}
      .negRed {text-align: right; background-color: rgb(250,200,200);}
      .posNorm {text-align: right; background-color: rgb(255,255,255)}
      .nofoc {font-weight: bold; text-align: right;}
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="pr">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="thd">
          <th>s/n</th>
          <th>Ddn1</th>
          <th>Ddn2</th>
          <th>Ddn3</th>
          <th>Ddn4</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin" onkeyup="update((this));" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot id="tft">
        <tr>
          <td class="nofoc">Total</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

    <script>
      function update(element) {
        var a = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].value;
        var c = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].children[0].value;
        var e = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0].value;
        var g = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[4].children[0].value;
        console.log(a, c, e, g);

        <!-- Set all NaN value to 0 -->
          if (a === "" || isNaN(a)) {
            a = 0;
          }
        if (c === "" || isNaN(c)) {
          c = 0;
        }
        if (e === "" || isNaN(e)) {
          e = 0;
        }
        if (g === "" || isNaN(g)) {
          g = 0;
        }

        var b = parseInt(a);
        var d = parseInt(c);
        var f = parseInt(e);
        var h = parseInt(g);

        <!-- Alert for -ve input, alphabets... cell turns red -->
          if (b < 0) {
            element.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
          } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
                 }
        if (d < 0) {
          element.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
        } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
               }
        if (f < 0) {
          element.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
        } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
               }
        if (h < 0) {
          element.parentElement.parentElement.children[4].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
        } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[4].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
               }

        var y = (b + d + f + h);    <!-- Sum deductions -->

          <!-- Alert for NaN value.. cell turns red -->
            if (isNaN(y)) {
              y = 0;
            }

        <!-- Alert for -ve input. Total = 0 & cell turns red -->
          if (b < 0 || d < 0 || f < 0 || h < 0) {
            y = 0;
            element.parentElement.parentElement.children[5].children[0].setAttribute("class", "negRed");
          } else {element.parentElement.parentElement.children[5].children[0].setAttribute("class", "posNorm");
                 }

        element.parentElement.parentElement.children[5].children[0].value = y;

        var table = document.getElementById("pr"); 
        var nuRow = document.getElementById("pr").rows.length;
        var t = nuRow - 1;
        var colSum1, colSum2, colSum3, colSum4, colSum5;
        var v;
        var row;

        for(v = 1; v < t; v++){
          row = table.rows[t];
          colSum1 = colSum1 + b;
          colSum2 = colSum2 + d;
          colSum3 = colSum3 + f;
          colSum4 = colSum4 + h;
          colSum5 = colSum5 + y;

          element.row.children[1].children[0].value = colSum1;
          element.row.children[2].children[0].value = colSum2;
          element.row.children[3].children[0].value = colSum3;
          element.row.children[4].children[0].value = colSum4;
          element.row.children[5].children[0].value = colSum5;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Instead of all these things above, you can simply use jQuery to do your work. Already, your list of columns and rows are fixed! Just found out that you even have included jQuery for no reason!

Final Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chem help</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      * {font-family: Segoe UI;}
      th {font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; 
        border-style: solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
      td {font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; 
        border-style: solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
      #sn {text-align: right;}
      .fin {text-align: right;}
      .fin:focus {background-color: rgb(255,255,150);}
      .negRed {text-align: right; background-color: rgb(250,200,200);}
      .posNorm {text-align: right; background-color: rgb(255,255,255)}
      .nofoc {font-weight: bold; text-align: right;}
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="pr">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="thd">
          <th>s/n</th>
          <th>Ddn1</th>
          <th>Ddn2</th>
          <th>Ddn3</th>
          <th>Ddn4</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin1" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin2" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin3" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin4" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin1" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin2" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin3" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin4" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin1" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin2" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin3" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="fin4" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot id="tft">
        <tr>
          <th>Total</th>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc fin1" readonly /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc fin2" readonly /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc fin3" readonly /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc fin4" readonly /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="nofoc" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("input").keyup(function () {
          col = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
          $(".fin1").each(function () {
            console.log(($(this).val()));
            if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val() != "")
              col[0] += parseInt($(this).val());
          });
          $(".fin2").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val() != "")
              col[1] += parseInt($(this).val());
          });
          $(".fin3").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val() != "")
              col[2] += parseInt($(this).val());
          });
          $(".fin4").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val() != "")
              col[3] += parseInt($(this).val());
          });
          col[4] = parseInt(col[0]) + parseInt(col[1]) + parseInt(col[2]) + parseInt(col[3]);
          i = 0;
          $("tfoot tr input").each(function () {
            $(this).val(col[i++]);
          });
          $("tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find(".nofoc").val(
              ((!isNaN($(this).find(".fin1").val())) ? parseInt($(this).find(".fin1").val()) : 0) +
              ((!isNaN($(this).find(".fin2").val())) ? parseInt($(this).find(".fin2").val()) : 0) +
              ((!isNaN($(this).find(".fin3").val())) ? parseInt($(this).find(".fin3").val()) : 0) +
              ((!isNaN($(this).find(".fin4").val())) ? parseInt($(this).find(".fin4").val()) : 0)
            );
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Txs. But this isn't working. Don't know if you tried it. The sum of each row gives NaN. For the column, the result is same for each of the columns (repeating itself). A math calc. is being used for the Math instead of the addition. Also I will prefer to use javascript for this exercise for now (if possible) I guess since it works for the row, it should work for the combination of both rows & columns. Appreciate

Comment: We do not write code for you. But still I managed to spend about an hour to write something for you. Can't you proceed from here?

Comment: Txs @Praveen Kumar et all.I have been able to solve the problem using your method. I am not very strong yet in jQuery. I am a starter, using my experience of Fortran IV of the '80s to learn all these new things by myself @ age 60yr!!! Interesting. Reason, I am converting my in house excel-VBA apps to web based apps for personal use. Since thanks to you all. I wish u all the very best