# update sum of columns in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named `resources` with the following columns:

```
ress1 
ress2 
prod1 
prod2
```

I've tried the code indicated in the following links, but I'm still stuck...

[How to find sum of multiple columns in a table in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033340/how-to-find-sum-of-multiple-columns-in-a-table-in-sql-server-2005)

[Auto update sum of rows & columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153238/auto-update-sum-of-rows-columns-in-a-table)

[SQL How to Update SUM of column over group in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871217/sql-how-to-update-sum-of-column-over-group-in-same-table)

I want to run a script to `UPDATE ress1 = ress1 + prod1` and the same with the `ress2`. So I want to update into a column the sum of the column itself and the corresponding column, doing that for every rows from the table.

Here is some code that seems easy for me, but not working...

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM ro_map";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$new_a = $row['a'] + $row['c'];
$new_b = $row['b'] + $row['d'];

"UPDATE ro_map SET a = '$new_a',b = '$new_b'";
}
```

Ah...really sorry, guys :D I use mysql (with wampp server and HeidiSQL). And running this code don t give me any error (  if($conn->$sql == TRUE) will give me TRUE...
SOLVED! Cool, thanks all, I've learned something :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? And can you define "not working"? We don't know what that means. Do you get an error? Wrong result? And I would urge you to look into parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You should distinguish MySQL and SQL Server; until that you are dealing with one product but reading about the other one

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating it.  If I understand you correctly, you can just do this in one transaction:

```
Update    resources
Set       ress1 = ress1 + prod1,
          ress2 = ress2 + prod2
```

Comment: The OP is using single quotes where they should be using single quotes

Comment: @Strawberry So they are... I'm not sure what I was looking at yesterday...  thanks for pointing that out!